# VBA - Refresh All Tables Except in Workbook

Tags: vba

I have a workbook with a source table (In Sheet A) and power query tables (In Sheets C & D). The problem with the using ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll is because whenever I replace the source data via copy/paste, this table also gets refreshed and the new data is lost. Say I have 4 worksheets (A, B, C, D) and only want to update the table in C & D. Here's what I tried to implement but did not work:

```
Sub Macro()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "A" Or "B" Then
      Range("A1").Select
      Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      End If
   Next ws
End Sub
```

Or if there's a way to only refresh power query tables in my workbook, that would work too.

Comment: `If ws.Name <> "A" And ws.Name <> "B" Then`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Macro()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> "A" And ws.Name <> "B" Then
          ws.Range("a1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      End If
   Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an expression error - "We couldn't find an Excel table named 'Table_query_57345'. Update: Oh forgot I just changed the name of my source table. I'll see if your solution works now.

Comment: Turns out Excel has an option under connection properties that allow you to disable "RefreshAll" for that table, so just did that and kept the RefreshAll in my code. Thanks for the help!